# Tagalog y español

Tags: gramática, tagalog

El idioma de Filipinas tiene una gran cantidad de palabras de origen español. Pero, ¿es ello suficiente para aseverar que saber español facilita aprender tagalog?

Comment: No estoy 100% en esto, pero creo que lo que pasa es que los españoles colonizaron las Filipinas y así llegaron muchos términos y nombres españoles.

Comment: Creo que esta sería una buena pregunta para el [stack de linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), donde posiblemetne podría tener mejores respuestas, pero aquí no termina de cuadrar con el [tipo de preguntas consideradas on-topic](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque lo siguiente es anecdótico, viene bien compartirlo. Está en un foro de [aprendizaje de idiomas](http://forums.tomisimo.org/showthread.php?t=13722) y quien escribe es un hablante nativo de tagalo, bilingüe (como es habitual) en inglés:

> Since many Filipino words were derived from Spanish (owing to our
>   country's colonial history), Filipino speakers already have a head
>   start when it comes to vocabulary. Here are a few Filipino words that
>   mean the same as their similarly-sounding Spanish counterparts: nobyo,
>   mundo, tinidor, kabayo (caballo), banyo, relo, sobre, takilya, huwes
>   (juez), berde. (…)
>
> Furthermore, grammar rules that may be uncommon in English, such as
>   the noun-adjective order and the verb-subject order in passive voice,
>   are normal in the Filipino language. For me, this helped me "accept"
>   these grammar rules rules quite quickly.

De manera que la similitud léxica y alguna similitud gramatical ayudan, al menos, al hablante de tagalo a aprender castellano.

En otro sitio donde se habla de [aprendizaje de idiomas](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/learning-spanish/27104-know-spanish-easy-to-learn-tagalog/) se afirma que saber castellano "ya es saber algo de tagalo" y vuelve a mencionar la similitud de la estructura de voz pasiva y, en un segundo plano, la similitud léxica, con énfasis en la coincidencia de los numerales, que el tagalo toma tal cual de los castellanos (con las alteraciones fonológicas menores del caso).

A pesar de todo esto siento que se está exagerando la facilidad de adquisición del idioma. La similitud léxica es una gran ayuda, pero la gramática suele ser más difícil de adquirir, y el tagalo tiene una gramática y una morfología absolutamente diferentes de la del castellano o, por caso, de la de cualquier otra lengua occidental a las que habitualmente tenemos acceso.

El tagalo utiliza un [alineamiento morfosintáctico inusual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesian_alignment), propio de las lenguas austronésicas, en el cual la función del tópico de la proposición se marca en el verbo utilizando afijos (prefijos, sufijos y a veces infijos), de manera que cada verbo puede tener varias "voces" además de lo que nosotros llamaríamos activa y pasiva. Estas "voces" son sintácticamente paralelas unas con otras y tienen como efecto secundario marcar el carácter definido o indefinido de los argumentos. El [tópico o tema](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tema_y_rema), además, va habitualmente al final de la proposición. Toda esta estructura es absolutamente extraña a nuestra forma de construir proposiciones en castellano (o en cualquier lengua indoeuropea, por caso). En castellano hay sólo dos voces, una claramente más compleja que la otra y mucho menos usada, y el tópico o tema es normalmente colocado al comienzo de la proposición (siendo esto —el *topic fronting*— lo más habitual universalmente).

Quedaría por ver si existen (yo no los encontré) estudios que comparen rigurosamente la facilidad de aprendizaje del tagalo entre hablantes y no hablantes de castellano.